# Vue push unique values to a list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
var vue_app = new Vue({
  el: '#id1',
  data: {
    v1:[],
  },

  methods:{
      pushUnique: function() {
      this.v1.push({'id':1,'name':'josh'});
      this.v1.push({'id':1,'name':'josh'}); //this should not work.
      },

  },
});
```

In above code the second push should not execute. I would like to keep `id` unique. How can this be done in Vue.

THanks

Comment: `if (!this.vi.some(el => el.id === obj.id)) this.vi.push(obj);` (this has nothing to do with Vue btw, this is just about pushing an object into an array)

Comment: if `vi` is supposed to only have unique values, maybe if would be better as an object?

Comment: _"this should not work"_  it would be good if you could explain what it _should_ do

Answer (score 0):

I would move to storing data in an object (keyed by `id`) and use a computed property to produce your `v1` array. For example

```
data: {
  v1obj: {}
},
computed: {
  v1 () {
    return Object.keys(this.v1obj).map(id => ({ id, name: this.v1obj[id] }))
  }
}
```

Then you can use methods like `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` to check for existing keys...

```
methods: {
  pushUnique () {
    let id = 1
    let name = 'josh'
    if (!this.v1obj.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      this.v1obj[id] = name
    }
  }
}
```